# Why sulfuric acid is used in esterification of alcohol and carboxylic acid anhydride?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, catalysis, esters

I have a question regarding why sulfuric acid is used in esterification of alcohol and carboxylic acid anhydride.

I know that in case of esterification of alcohol and carboxylic acid, sulfuric acid remove water formed as product and it keeps reaction to proceed in forward direction.

$$\ce{CH3OH + CH3COOH <=>[H2SO4] CH3OCOCH3 + H2O}$$

But in case of esterification of alcohol and carboxylic acid anhydride there is no water formed so what is the real reason of using sulfuric acid in this case.

$$\ce{CH3OH + (CH3CO)O2 <=>[H2SO4] CH3OCOCH3 + CH3COOH}$$

Comment: Concentrated sulfuric acid is anhydrous. All the other common concentrated acids contain water.

Comment: @MaxW  But what is the purpose of sulfuric acid in second reaction if there is no water being released that it could remove.

Comment: What is unclear about the word "catalyst"?

Comment: @Mithoron How sulfuric acid promote reaction even if there is no water to be removed? How it catalyse reaction? What's the the process?

Comment: @MaxW Not completely anhydrous. @ OP Your "water removal" is a misnomer, at best. What acids do? Protonate. Then again, with anhydride, this reaction should go pretty well even without it being additionally protonated.

Answer (score 0):

To start, we should consider the physical state of reactants. We mostly take aqueous solutions of methanol and anhydride for reactions. So one of the reasons to use sulfuric acid can be to remove water as soon as product is formed as in the presence of water, the reaction is highly reversible.
Second reason could be that the reactions proceed with maximum efficiency (rate) in an acidic medium (it acts as catalyst also), so in order to maintain acidic buffer sulfuric acid is used.

I hope my answer helps.

Comment: The second reason sounds good but the first reason that sulfuric acid would remove water is bit strange as in aqueous medium there is a lot of water and sulfuric acid cannot just evaporate entire glass of water and leave behind only products and also acid anhydride would just react with water so this reaction cannot be done in aqueous medium.